# ls: can't open '.': Permission denied in podman container

Tags: permissions, container, podman

I have the following directory (on my host):

```
drwxr-xr-x@    - mnj  mnj   15 Dec 21:02   -- mocks/
```

It's owned by me (mnj) and everyone should have at least READ access to it.
I'm running a podman container (without sudo) based on the following docker-compose service:

```yml
  mountebank:
    image: jkris/mountebank:latest
    hostname: mountebank
    volumes:
      - ./mocks/:/mountebank
    command: >
      --configfile=/mountebank/imposters.json.ejs
      --allowInjection
```

The directory `mocks` should appear as `/mountebank` inside of the container.

Mountebank fails with an error:

> Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/mountebank/imposters.json.ejs'

When I get into the container's  shell, I see the following in `/`:

```
bash-4.3# ls -lah
total 0
dr-xr-xr-x    1 root     root          38 Dec 16 11:48 .
dr-xr-xr-x    1 root     root          38 Dec 16 11:48 ..
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           4 Feb 28  2022 bin
drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root         360 Dec 16 11:48 dev
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          22 Dec 16 11:48 etc
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           0 Mar  6  2019 home
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          72 Feb 28  2022 lib
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          28 Mar  6  2019 media
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           0 Mar  6  2019 mnt
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         168 Dec 15 21:02 mountebank
dr-xr-xr-x  486 nobody   nobody         0 Dec 16 11:48 proc
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          40 Dec 16 11:48 run
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         792 Mar  6  2019 sbin
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           0 Mar  6  2019 srv
dr-xr-xr-x   13 nobody   nobody         0 Dec 16 11:37 sys
drwxrwxrwt    1 root     root          28 Feb 28  2022 tmp
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          18 Feb 28  2022 usr
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           6 Feb 28  2022 var
```

It seems that `mountebank` should still be READable for anyone.
However, when I `cd mountebank` and try to `ls`, I get this error:

> ls: can't open '.': Permission denied

Why is that?

Comment: you probably want to specify the `:Z` access modifier at the end of your volume line. Can you try whether that helps?

Comment: Yes, it does work. Similarly, I just tried adding `privileged` flag, which also did work. Could you explain why that is necessary? I'm having problem understanding why the READ permission does not work without any additions, like `:Z` or `privileged`.